# How to use google URL shortener in UI iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-url-shortener

I recently get a google URL shortener. I tried to integrate inside a `UITableViewController`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But I realised, My UI(cell) creation is completed, before complete the URL shorting process. I did what was,

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:cell.postedText.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [cell.postedText.text length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
        [OHGoogleShortener sharedService];
        [OHGoogleShortener shorten:[cell.postedText.text lowercaseString] WithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                return;
            }else{
                NSLog(@"dic::%@", response);
                cell.postedText.text = [cell.postedText.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[url absoluteString] withString:[response objectForKey:@"id"]];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

I'm replacing the links in a textview with the URL shortener service. This is not working on data loading. How may I fix this?

Comment: Does the dict:: output appear on the console? Set a breakpoint at cell.postedText.text. If the debugger stops, see if this line is executed in the main thread.